# localytics angular-chosen no-results-text with button

Tags: angularjs

I need to add the searched content in to the list,if the searched value not in list.
In no-result-text i'm able to insert the input element,but ng-click function in that element is not working.

This the screenshot after searching for the not listed item with button:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4NYZ.png)

Sample Snippet,search for non listed item.you'll get add button in dropdown.
The issue is add button function is not called.

Controller:

```js
  angular.module('test',['localytics.directives'])
  
  .controller('ctrl',function($scope){

    $scope.noResultsText ="'<input id=\"BtnId\" type=\"button\" value=\"add\" ng-        click=\"ClickFunction(searchValue)\" />'"

    $scope.ClickFunction=function(searchValue){
    alert(searchValue);
    }
    
    $scope.alphabets=['a','b','c','d'];
    
    })
```

```html
<style>
/* @group Base */
.chosen-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 1010;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
  left: 0;
}
.chosen-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Single Chosen */
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  height: 23px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(52%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #f4f4f4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px white inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-default {
  color: #999;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 26px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single-with-deselect span {
  margin-right: 38px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 26px;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') -42px 1px no-repeat;
  font-size: 1px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-single.chosen-disabled .chosen-single abbr:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 100%;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 2px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1010;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: white url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px, -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(1%, #eeeeee), color-stop(15%, #ffffff));
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px, -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px, -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px, -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px, linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-drop {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Results */
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  max-height: 240px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 15px;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result {
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.disabled-result {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
  background-color: #3875d7;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #3875d7), color-stop(90%, #2a62bc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  color: #fff;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.no-results {
  display: list-item;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-result {
  display: list-item;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li em {
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Multi Chosen */
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(1%, #eeeeee), color-stop(15%, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  cursor: text;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field .default {
  color: #999;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3px 0 3px 5px;
  padding: 3px 20px 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px white inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #333;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') -42px 1px no-repeat;
  font-size: 1px;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-disabled {
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  color: #666;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-focus {
  background: #d4d4d4;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-focus .search-choice-close {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-results {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Active  */
.chosen-container-active .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #eeeeee), color-stop(80%, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
}
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
  border-left: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: -18px 2px;
}
.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  color: #111 !important;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Disabled Support */
.chosen-disabled {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-disabled .chosen-single {
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-disabled .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
  cursor: default;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Right to Left */
.chosen-rtl {
  text-align: right;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single span {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 26px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single-with-deselect span {
  margin-left: 38px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single div {
  right: auto;
  left: 3px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single abbr {
  right: auto;
  left: 26px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li {
  float: right;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  direction: rtl;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
  margin: 3px 5px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 19px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  right: auto;
  left: 4px;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search,
.chosen-rtl .chosen-drop {
  left: 9999px;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-results {
  margin: 0 0 4px 4px;
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
  border-right: none;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px;
  background: white url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px, -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(1%, #eeeeee), color-stop(15%, #ffffff));
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px, -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px, -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px, -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px, linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  direction: rtl;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: 6px 2px;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: -12px 2px;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Retina compatibility */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-down span,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-up span {
    background-image: url('chosen-sprite@2x.png') !important;
    background-size: 52px 37px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  }
}
/* @end */
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.8.0
(function() {
  var __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

  angular.module('localytics.directives', []);

  angular.module('localytics.directives').directive('chosen', [
    '$timeout', function($timeout) {
      var CHOSEN_OPTION_WHITELIST, NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP, isEmpty, snakeCase;
      NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP = /^\s*(.*?)(?:\s+as\s+(.*?))?(?:\s+group\s+by\s+(.*))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w]*)|(?:\(\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*,\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*\)))\s+in\s+(.*?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.*?))?$/;
      CHOSEN_OPTION_WHITELIST = ['noResultsText', 'allowSingleDeselect', 'disableSearchThreshold', 'disableSearch', 'enableSplitWordSearch', 'inheritSelectClasses', 'maxSelectedOptions', 'placeholderTextMultiple', 'placeholderTextSingle', 'searchContains', 'singleBackstrokeDelete', 'displayDisabledOptions', 'displaySelectedOptions', 'width'];
      snakeCase = function(input) {
        return input.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function($1) {
          return "_" + ($1.toLowerCase());
        });
      };
      isEmpty = function(value) {
        var key;
        if (angular.isArray(value)) {
          return value.length === 0;
        } else if (angular.isObject(value)) {
          for (key in value) {
            if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        return true;
      };
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        terminal: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
          var chosen, defaultText, disableWithMessage, empty, initOrUpdate, match, options, origRender, removeEmptyMessage, startLoading, stopLoading, valuesExpr, viewWatch;
          element.addClass('localytics-chosen');
          options = scope.$eval(attr.chosen) || {};
          angular.forEach(attr, function(value, key) {
            if (__indexOf.call(CHOSEN_OPTION_WHITELIST, key) >= 0) {
              return options[snakeCase(key)] = scope.$eval(value);
            }
          });
          startLoading = function() {
            return element.addClass('loading').attr('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
          };
          stopLoading = function() {
            return element.removeClass('loading').attr('disabled', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
          };
          chosen = null;
          defaultText = null;
          empty = false;
          initOrUpdate = function() {
            if (chosen) {
              return element.trigger('chosen:updated');
            } else {
              chosen = element.chosen(options).data('chosen');
              return defaultText = chosen.default_text;
            }
          };
          removeEmptyMessage = function() {
            empty = false;
            return element.attr('data-placeholder', defaultText);
          };
          disableWithMessage = function() {
            empty = true;
            return element.attr('data-placeholder', chosen.results_none_found).attr('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
          };
          if (ngModel) {
            origRender = ngModel.$render;
            ngModel.$render = function() {
              origRender();
              return initOrUpdate();
            };
            if (attr.multiple) {
              viewWatch = function() {
                return ngModel.$viewValue;
              };
              scope.$watch(viewWatch, ngModel.$render, true);
            }
          } else {
            initOrUpdate();
          }
          attr.$observe('disabled', function() {
            return element.trigger('chosen:updated');
          });
          if (attr.ngOptions && ngModel) {
            match = attr.ngOptions.match(NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP);
            valuesExpr = match[7];
            scope.$watchCollection(valuesExpr, function(newVal, oldVal) {
              var timer;
              return timer = $timeout(function() {
                if (angular.isUndefined(newVal)) {
                  return startLoading();
                } else {
                  if (empty) {
                    removeEmptyMessage();
                  }
                  stopLoading();
                  if (isEmpty(newVal)) {
                    return disableWithMessage();
                  }
                }
              });
            });
            return scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
              if (typeof timer !== "undefined" && timer !== null) {
                return $timeout.cancel(timer);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
</script>

<div ng-app='test'>
  <div  ng-controller="ctrl">
<select  chosen no-results-text={{noResultsText}} ng-options="alphabet for alphabet in alphabets" ng-model="alphabet" >
                    <option value="">Select one</option>
                </select>
  </div>
   </div>
```